# git clone and new permissions

Tags: wordpress, git, permissions, file-permissions

I have a repository on github with preset wordpress with a few plugins. I cloned it into my mamp folder to start working on a new project. However something is wrong with the file permissions. During WordPress installation wp could not create wp-config file, so I had to create it manually and when saving it requested an admin password to do so. If I want to update a plugin while in the admin area of this new wordpress site it requires ftp credentials, while if I go to another site in the same mamp folder I can click update and the plugin is updated. I checked the permissions for both wordpress site folders and they are 755. My question is what could trigger such behavior with permissions and how can it be prevented in the future?

Comment: Can you share the exact permission error you got?

Comment: if I try to create a directory with transmit it returns 'You don’t have permission to save the file “untitled folder” in the folder “wp-pip”.' if I do the same in terminal it returns 'Permission denied'

Comment: if I git clone the same repository to my desktop I don't have these permission issues, I checked permissions and both desktop and documents have 700

Comment: sounds like a mac file permission issue more than a git or wordpress issue.. you might want to check 2 things, the **parent folder permission** and **ownership** of these folder/files.

Comment: parent folder permissions are set to 755, the ownership for both files are set to me